# Download the project from a repository without losing any project files. Sourcetree

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

When I upload a project from the local machine to the server repository, and try to download it from the server to another machine I am always missing some .dll files and cannot build the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're likely keeping externally needed DLLs in your bin folder, which would not be added to (many) source controls by default, as the DLLs in your bin folder get updated after each build.

The not adding bin to source is the correct route, you have a few options on what what you would need to do:

1. Use nuget packages that get restored automatically during build
2. add the DLLS to a separate folder (I like to use "extLib" or "3rdParty" as my folder name, and add *that* to source, referencing the DLLs in the separate folder.
3. ensure all machines have required DLLs/SDKs installed on the machine

They are listed in (my) order of preference, but that's just my own opinion.

Comment: Totally agree. The last thing you want is a 20 GB repo because you added all the project's dll's to source control.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because repo's ignore file is ignoring those file types. Check you .gitignore file in the root of the repo.